# how do i read data from textfile and push back to a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, ifstream, getline

I have a text file, "test.txt" which stored my data as follow, there's a spacing between each delimiter field..

Code: Name: Coy

```
045: Ted: Coy1
054: Red: Coy2
```

How do i read this data from file and insert this into a vector?

```
vector <Machine> data;
Machine machine

void testclass(){
ifstream inFile("test.txt");
if (!inFile){
    cout << "File couldn't be opened." << endl;
    return;
}
while(!inFile.eof()){
    string code,name,coy;
    getline(inFile,code, ':');
    getline(inFile,name, ':');
    getline(inFile,coy, ':');
data.push_back(machine)

}
```

but it seems to have a problem with pushing the data

Comment: [`while(!inFile.eof())` is wrong here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong). Which book instructed you to do that?

Answer (score 1):

As others have already pointed out, one problem is that you're reading the data into local variables (`code`, `name` and `coy`), but never putting those values into the `machine` before you add it to the vector.

That's *not* the *only* problem though. Your `while (!infile.eof())` is wrong as well (in fact, `while (!whatever.eof())` is essentially *always* wrong). What you normally want to do is continue reading while reading was successful. `whatever.eof()` will only return true after you try to do a read and you've reached the end of the file *before* the read commenced.

The way I'd normally fix that would be to define a stream extractor for your Machine class:

```
class Machine { 
// ...

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, Machine &m) { 
        std::getline(is, m.code, ':');
        std::getline(is, m.name, ':');
        std::getline(is, m.coy, ":");
        return is;
    }
};
```

Using this, you can do your reading something like this:

```
std::vector<Machine> machines;

Machine machine;

while (infile >> machine) 
    machines.push_back(machine);
```

Once you've defined a stream extractor for the type, there's another possibility to consider as well though; you can initialize the vector from a pair of iterators:

```
std::vector<Machine> machines((std::istream_iterator<Machine>(infile)),
                               std::istream_iterator<Machine>());
```

...and that will read all the data from the file (using the `operator>>` we defined above) and use it to initialize the `machines` vector.

Answer (score 0):

you should read the data and put them into member variables of an object of Machine class. and then put that object on the Vector.