# How do i read data from binary file and push back to a vector?

Tags: c++, fstream, stdvector, ifstream

I apologize in advance for my lack of explanation because I am not good at English.
I created a binary file that stores these objects. I want to read it and push back on the vector, but I don't know what to do.

```
class Player
{
    string name;
    int score;
    int id;
    size_t num; 
    char* p;
};
```

These functions were used when writing to binary files.

```
void write(ostream& os) 
{
        os.write((char*)this, sizeof(Player));
        os.write((char*)p, num);
}
```

This is the operator overload function of the class.
Below it is the main function, which is written in this way to read the file, but is not working poorly.

```
istream& operator>> (istream& is, Player& p)
{
    getline(is, p.name, '\0');
    is.read((char*)&p.score, sizeof(int));
    is.read((char*)&p.id, sizeof(int));
    is.read((char*)&p.num, sizeof(size_t));

    return is;
}

int main()
{
    ifstream in{ "Myfile", ios::binary };
    vector<Player> players(istream_iterator<Player>(in), {});
}
```

What should I do to read the file?
I want to read the data of each object, but I think more data is being read than I want.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Player
{
    string name;
    int score;
    int id;
    size_t num;
    char* p;

public:
    Player(): name{NULL}, score{0}, id{0}, num{0}, p{nullptr}
    {}

    Player(string name, int score, int id, size_t num) :
        name{ name }, score{ score }, id{ id }, num{ num }, p{ new char[num] }
    {}
    
    ~Player() 
    { 
        delete[] p; 
    }

    /*Player(const Player& other) : name{ other.name }, score{ other.score }, id{ other.id }, num{ other.num }, p{ new char[num] }
    {
        memcpy(p, other.p, num);
    }*/

    void write(ostream& os) {
        os.write((char*)this, sizeof(Player));
        os.write((char*)p, num);
    }

    friend istream& operator>> (istream& is, Player& p);
};

istream& operator>> (istream& is, Player& p)
{
    getline(is, p.name, '\0');
    is.read((char*)&p.score, sizeof(int));
    is.read((char*)&p.id, sizeof(int));
    is.read((char*)&p.num, sizeof(size_t));

    return is;
}

int main()
{
    ifstream in{ "Myfile", ios::binary };
    vector<Player> players(istream_iterator<Player>(in), {});

    in.close();
}
```

Comment: _is not working poorly_ means _is working decently_. Probably you meant something else. As a general suggestion, you probably just want to use `std::copy`.

Comment: By the way, your code is not compilable nor runnable. Please, provide a [repro].

Comment: Your last example doesn't even compile either. Please, adjust.

Answer (score 0):

Given the scarce information you provided, I believe probably this what you're looking for:

```cpp
    std::copy(
            std::istream_iterator<int>(in),
            std::istream_iterator<int>(),
            players.begin()
            );
```

You can `#include <iterator>` to have the `std::istream_iterator`s available.

Comment: I think it's because you don't have a file to read, and I don't have a detailed code because writing the file was provided by another program. So I only posted the code of the reading section. If you read like that, p.score, p.id, and p.num will have strange values. Is there any other way to read this?

Comment: @109, "it's because"? What's is "it"?

Comment: This means that the code will not be compiled.
I wanted to solve the problem, so I looked at other things, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545120/how-do-i-read-data-from-textfile-and-push-back-to-a-vector I thought my situation was similar to the question here. However, if you read this and write a code similar to it, the file won't be read.

Comment: @109 i don't understand what you write, sorry.

Comment: I think it's because I lack the ability to explain. I'm sorry.
Earlier, you said that the code is not compiled.
I think that's because I'm not creating a file, but I'm using the file I received.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545120/how-do-i-read-data-from-textfile-and-push-back-to-a-vector
I think the question asked by the questioner on this link is similar to mine.
I want to get the information of the object from the binary file and save it to the vector.
However, when I run my code, 'name' stores the value, but not the other variables.